# How to securly pass a password to a different application with Struts

Tags: java, security, struts2

I have an application which we use as a gateway to several other applications.  The user logs in through the gateway application using a web service to verify the login.  After the user is logged in  they can choose which application to go to next.  I am using the following code to redirect to the new application

```
<result name="appName" type="redirect">
    <param name="location">${url}</param>
    <param name="userId">${dnrUserId}</param>
    <param name="userPassword">${userPassword}</param>
</result>
```

The issue is this exposes the userPassword in the redirect url.  What is the best way to solve this? Can I encrypt the password with Java before I send it and then have the second application unencrypt it?

Comment: The login should be handled on the back end anyway. If it's not HTTPS, then yeah, this is pretty much an awful way to do it--but that's just what redirects do. You can manipulate it however you want before you send it.

Comment: What do you mean the login should be handled on the back end?

Comment: Log in to single system. That generates token you pass instead of password. SSO.

Comment: The applications we redirect to have to access the same web service we use to validate the user login so they have to have the password unless we force the user to re-enter it. I looked at SSO but I don't think it works in our situation.

Comment: Maybe you should fix that then? In any case, are you not using HTTPS? If not, ugh. But ultimately I don't understand the issue--you can encode/decode parameters however you want, although I'd probably add a time-dependent key in the encrypted param value so if they wait too long it's no longer valid. There essentially an unlimited number of ways this could be handled, all of which would be unnecessary with a back-end fix.

Comment: We are using https, but the url shows up in some of the server error logs so we wanted the password to not be in plain text.  I will look at SSO again to see if we could make it work.  Thanks!